# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream

Tags: r, apache-hadoop

Im traying to integrate Hadoop and R, I was install the pachages rJava and Rhipe in R, I do this steps to start Hadoop and R:
-starting Hadoop services.,
-loading rJava and Rhipe packages by library function.
-Calling rhinit() to initialize Rhipe.
the problem here is when I call rhinit() funtion, it show this error:

> > Initializing Rhipe v0.73
> >     Error in .jnew("org/godhuli/rhipe/PersonalServer") : 
> >      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream'

please some helps to fixe this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused because the following environment variables are not set correctly
PKG_CONFIG_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
for my configuration, i should execute this:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH = /usr/local/lib 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/lib

also set this commands on R console:

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/hadoop/")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_BIN="/usr/local/hadoop/bin")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/conf")